# Immediately send most recent newsletter on successful newsletter subscription

Tags: feature-request, email, newsletter

My profile indicates

> Member for 5 years, 3 months

and I just now learned I can get weekly mails for tags or networks. Awesome!

I immediately signed up for newsletters of four interesting networks. Upon clicking four emailed confirmation links, I got four confirmation landing pages, with indications that I would receive mails on Thursday, Wednesday, Tuesday, Monday respectively.

I don't want to wait! When I subscribe you should immediately send me a copy of the previous week's newsletter, labelled as a welcome/preview!

Comment: In case if you are want to see the newsletter immediately, you can click the "preview" button against the expected site in the [Community Newsletter page](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters)

Comment: Those are **weekly** newsletters, meaning sent once a week. It won't be good idea to send "half baked" newsletter. If you want to see it right away then@Arulkumar is correct, just click the "preview" link.

Comment: thanks, good to know. btw i mean "last week's newsletter", editing